# How to create a basis for the span of a subset?

Tags: linear-algebra

[Subspace and Span Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hue3.png)

Given the question in the link above (it's an image), I row reduced to find that all three given vectors that span U are linearly independent, but I'm not sure how to proceed to find the missing part of the basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that in the basis, the first and the second vectors have a zero entry in the second and the first component respectively.

From this, we can easily find out that $(2,-6,-12,6)^T = 2(0,-3,-3,1)^T-2(-1,0,3,-2)^T$ and $(1,9,0,2)^T = (-3)(0,-3,-3,1)^T-(-1,0,3,-2)^T-3(0,0,2,-1)^T$.  Therefore, $x^T = (0,0,2,-1)^T$.

Finally, note that $(1,0,9,-4)^T = (-1)(-1,0,3,-2)^T+6(0,0,2,-1)^T$. We're done.

Comment: I see how you found x, but how did you find out the combinations of the vectors that equaled the vectors in the span? Is there a certain equation you used, or did you just try things out until it worked?

Comment: I just make use of the observation at the beginning and calculated them numerically.